# Enforcing vertical size in Grid component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently trying to create a layout where [a box is divided into multiple sections, where each is on top of another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvyGK.png). The middle grid item contains a List which most likely would become so long that it needs to be scrolled up and down. Because I want to divide this area into sections, I used Grid component to create this. This is the code I used to test it:

```
    return (
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
                <Grid container spacing={2} direction='column'>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Card>
                            ABCD
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <List sx={{overflow: 'auto'}}>
                            {displayRows()}
                        </List>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Card>
                            IJKL
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Divider orientation='vertical' flexItem/>
        </Grid>
    );
```

Where displayRow() returns an array of ListItems.
Problem is when the list size changed. When it is too long, [it messes with other components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmpEN.png). When the list is too small, [the card doesn't extend all the way until the next grid item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsAUn.png) (as in, the middle card should be long enough to touch the card that says "IJKL"). How can I make it so that the middle area is always as big as it can get, but only within the given space?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that spamming height="100%" works. It works, and it doesn't involve hardcoding heights into each elements so I suppose this is a valid solution.

```
            <Grid item xs={3} height='100%'>
                <Grid container spacing={1} height='100%' direction='column'>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Card sx={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>123</Card>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Card sx={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>123</Card>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Card sx={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>123</Card>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Card sx={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>123</Card>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Edit: Apparently, for a grid item that contains a list, it needs to have height of 0 for it to work as expected. Weird.

```
                    <Grid item xs={10} height='0'>
                        <List sx={{ overflow: 'auto', width: '100%', padding: 0, height: '100%'}}>
                            {displayRows()}
                        </List>
                    </Grid>
```